MYSQL Count occurences by Row
hoping someone can help.
I use a function in Excel to produce a semi-distinct reference but I need to be able to replicate it in MYSQL and am struggling at the minute.
In Excel I Countif by row but anchor in the top reference point, therefore indexing my list by a set criteria
example
I need to understand when a person has returned to a shop, this will then be joined to a new table by concatenating the Uniq & Count to (note the invoice is not Unique and can be added on to at a later time)



Uniq
Name
Fruit
Invoice
Checkout Time
Count




JohnApple12345
John
Apple
12345
16:00
1


BobOrange1211
Bob
Orange
1211
15:30
1


JohnApple12345
John
Apple
12345
16:45
2


FrankGrape1300
Frank
Grape
1300
11:00
1


JohnApple1000
John
Apple
1000
9:45
1


JohnApple12345
John
Apple
1234
20:00
3



How do I have this running count by Uniq? As stated in Excel I would run a countif on Uniq in the Count column bit only anchor 1 end of the formula so that it would increase as the list went on

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, especially #5 and #3.

Simplify your problem  and attached your query response @StewartJones

I dont know how to simplify this any more?????  Also expected outcome is in the question

@StewartJones attached MySql query

@ArtBindu No that isnt what I am after.  The Joined Car Type is just for Context, I only need an answer for the top table - perhaps I will just chop that out of the question to make it easier to understand

Don't do rapid change continuously in stackoverflow... Please explain your question with proper documentation  and follow the guideline: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055  @StewartJones

I seriously dont understand what you are not getting?

Hi, @Akina Have you any idea ?

If asking a new question please create a new question. Edit a question to add details, brevity or formatting - not to change the question itself.

Zach, I didnt change the question. I took out some information that was confusing Art. Why are all of you so judgmental??

This is supposed to be a place for help and because you cant answer the question, rather than trying to help, you keyboard warriors are being very abrupt and unhelpful

Your first table was:

Solution according to that table:
Use ROW_NUMBER() with partition by joined_cartype for every uniq.
MySQL query:
select *,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by uniq, joined_cartype) as count
from T
order by uniq, count, joined_cartype desc

Sample output:

Test query: db<>fiddle

Row number is not what I need - I need it to count +1 on Uniq

Yes, that's why I partition on uniq and then joined_cartype @StewartJones

One minute, your change your input table @StewartJones

Yes because you are obviously confused
